# Intercept Android GMail SSL connection

Tags: android, ssl, gmail, fiddler

Is it possible to route android gmail app traffic through my own HTTP proxy?

I know that I can install certificates onto android phone but I am not sure if gmail app has hard coded certificate information?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to decrypt pgp encrypted email. Andriod gmail app provides just 1 api (only read label and unread emails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use Fiddler with Android ICS by changing proxy settings on wi-fi network